# Some warning about manage.py migrate after upgrading to 6.4

Tags: kiwi-tcms

I upgrade TCMS from 6.3 to 6.4. when executing command "docker exec -it kiwi_web /Kiwi/manage.py migrate", I got following message:
Operations to perform:
  Apply all migrations: admin, attachments, auth, contenttypes, core, django_comments, kiwi_auth, linkreference, management, sessions, sites, testcases, testplans, testruns
Running migrations:
  No migrations to apply.
  Your models have changes that are not yet reflected in a migration, and so won't be applied.
  Run 'manage.py makemigrations' to make new migrations, and then re-run 'manage.py migrate' to apply them.

Shall I handle this? Not see this before.

Comment: Run "docker exec -it kiwi_web /Kiwi/manage.py makemigrations", then got "Migrations for 'testplans':
  venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tcms/testplans/migrations/0007_auto_20190114_0821.py
    - Alter field parent on historicaltestplan", run "docker exec -it kiwi_web /Kiwi/manage.py migrate" again. Just this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is issue with one of our dependent libraries which is being solved as we speak:
https://github.com/treyhunner/django-simple-history/issues/512

If you are working on a new Kiwi TCMS installation running `./manage.py migrate` for the first time is fine, trying to run it a second time will produce the error mentioned in original comment. This doesn't affect your DB at all.

If you are trying to upgrade from a previous version of Kiwi TCMS this will break the upgrades b/c migrate will refuse to execute. You can manually apply this change to your Docker image:
https://github.com/kiwitcms/Kiwi/pull/710/commits/61368aa254073bf6189bc3821f71d190c1a18501

or wait until we release the next version.