# Upgrade Kiwi TCMS from v6.3 to v6.4

Tags: kiwi-tcms

After upgrading from v6.3 to v6.4 the migrate command reports that the models have changed but no migrations exist.
As I don't want to break my existing installation: Can this warning be ignored? Do I have to follow the advice, what ist the risk of doing so?

```
docker container exec -it kiwi_web /Kiwi/manage.py migrate

Operations to perform:
  Apply all migrations: admin, attachments, auth, contenttypes, core, django_comments, kiwi_auth, linkreference, management, sessions, sites, testcases, testplans, testruns
Running migrations:
  No migrations to apply.
  Your models have changes that are not yet reflected in a migration, and so won't be applied.
  Run 'manage.py makemigrations' to make new migrations, and then re-run 'manage.py migrate' to apply them.
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Duplicate of
[Some warning about manage.py migrate after upgrading to 6.4](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54177838/some-warning-about-manage-py-migrate-after-upgrading-to-6-4)

Fixed in 6.5 (problem coming from a dependent library), see changelog